# Forcing $A_1x,\dotsc,A_Kx$ to lie in a proper subspace

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, graph-theory, matching-theory

*(This is a re-worked version of a question I asked several days ago.)*

Let $J$ be the all-one matrix with $m$ rows and $n$ columns, and suppose that $J=A_1+\dotsb+A_K$ is a decomposition of $J$ into a sum of zero-one matrices, each one having at most one element equal to $1$ in every row and in every column (forcing $K\ge\max\{m,n\}$). Must there exist a non-zero vector $x\in\mathbb C^n$ such that $A_1x,\dotsc,A_Kx$ all lie in a proper subspace of $\mathbb C^m$? (Notice that this is equivalent to the existence of non-zero $x\in\mathbb C^n$ and $y\in\mathbb C^m$ such that $y^tA_1x=\dotsb=y^tA_Kx=0$, so that $m$ and $n$ enter symmetrically the problem.)

The answer depends on $K$. If $K=\max\{m,n\}$, then assuming $m\le n$ for definitness, each matrix $A_i$ contains exactly one non-zero element in every row, and one can take $x=(1,\dotsc,1)$. If $K=m+n-1$, then $x\in\mathbb C^n$ with the property in question may fail to exist, though this is less immediate to see.

If some value of $K$ works, then so does any smaller value, by further decomposing the matrices $A_i$. Thus, the problem exhibits a threshold behavior. Is $m+n-2$ the threshold?

> Is it true that if $J=A_1+\dotsb+A_K$ with $K=m+n-2$ and $A_i$ as described above, then there exists $x\in\mathbb C^n\setminus\{0\}$ such that $A_1x,\dotsc,A_Kx$ all lie in a proper subspace of $\mathbb C^m$?

An equivalent restatement is as follows.

> Suppose that the complete bipartite graph with the partite sets $U$ and $V$ of sizes $m:=|U|$ and $n:=|V|$ is represented as a disjoint union of $m+n-2$ matchings. Must there exist non-zero functions $f\colon U\to\mathbb C$ and $g\colon V\to\mathbb C$ such that for each matching $M$,
>     $$ \sum_{(u,v)\in M} f(u)g(v)=0? $$

Notice that we are looking for a non-zero solution to a system of $m+n-2$ equations with $m+n$ variables; what makes the problem non-trivial is the fact that the equations are quadratic.

Comment: You can also ask if every $(m-1)(n-1)+1$-dimensional space of complex matrices contains a non-trivial matrix of rank 1. The quick literature search reveals that it should be known to humanity but is hidden behind the paywall, as usual.

Comment: @fedja: How would it help to know this?

Comment: Just forget that your matrices are $0,1$ or sum up to anything particular. You want a matrix of rank one orthogonal to some given $m+n-2$ matrices then. If you are not afraid of paywalls, the place to start is Ross, Maximum-rank array codes and their application to crisscross error correction.